# RAD GUI builder (preferably WYSIWYG) for developing a .Net GUI app to run on Linux

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, monodevelop

I want to build a rather complicated GUI app on the .Net framework. The app will have the following graphical capabilities:

1. Plotting/updating realtime data
2. Allow manual (using mouse) drawing/dragging/editing of lines etc on a plot
3. Allow selecting of graphical objects/shapes on a plot and drag/drirop to a new location on the plot

Ideally, I would like to use VS to do my initial development, because the VSIDE is (understandably) much more sophisticated than the monodevelop tools. However, I will be running the application and maintaining the codebase (once the development phase is completed), on Linux, using monodevelop.

It is important for this reason, that I make sure that I do not use any .Net components that have not yet been ported over to mono.

Given the graphical functional requirements above, I would like to know if I can expect to be able to develop such an app on Windows and then port to monodevelop?.

I am aware that components like WPF have not been ported to mono, so are there any other .Net GUI components (available on mono) that I can use in my application (to make the port possible)?

Answer (score 1):

From a past experience start with a Windows Forms plain app. If you want the port to be as clean as possible forget about complex UI components, you can always use your custom controls but check third-party ones you use don't call Win32 API directly. That you can do it within Visual Studio (check [this plugin](http://mono-tools.com/Debug.aspx) for more productivity) but I want to warn you about two things:

1. Interfaces built with Visual Studio (WinForms) when running on Linux look awful.
2. If you want a clean UI take a look at [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp)

Comment: +1 for the Gtk# link. However, it does seem to be a little light on the GUI widgets front (I may be mistaken). If no better GUI builder alternatives appear, I'll accept this answer and go down the Gtk# approach instead.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Particularly we develop a stock trading simulator (pretty complex UI) and don't have any kind of problem. One thing I'll suggest you is to give a try to Glade (http://glade.gnome.org/) to build the UI. I know your question is about using VS but using Glade + GTK# with mono is a productive experience also. Give it a try.

Comment: That sounds very interesting, that you are building a complicated GUI on mono. Could you please tell me how you are using Glade and mono to create the GUIs?. I don't have to use VS if I don't need to. I would prefer to build on Linux (since thats the OS the apps will run on), but I haven't found any good RAD GUI tools on Linux yet, so I am very interested in hearing how you are doing  it. I will change the question title.